# iOS autorotate sometimes not working

Tags: ios, uikit, landscape-portrait, autorotate

We're developing an iOS application which supports both iPad and iPhone. For iPad all our screens are locked to landscape orientation. For iPhone we have a mix where certain view controllers are always in portrait and other ones are always in landscape.

**Problem:** Occasionally (~1 out of 10-20 times trying to reproduce using the same flow from the app startup) the landscape view controller on iPhone won't autorotate when starting it from the portrait oriented device which breaks the UI.

[Autorotate failed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IPTbU.png)

**Additional information:**

1. This issue reproduces both on the device (iPhone 7) and simulator running 10.1 iOS. We're building in XCode 8.1.
2. I don't think we have seen this issue before upgrading to iOS 10 / XCode 8 (90% sure here)
3. It seems to only start happening after you force close the app once.
4. It doesn't seem to be the problem with orientation handling setup since it works fine for the most of time (even when rotating device and starting this view controller from various orientations). We use `supportedInterfaceOrientations` and `shouldAutorotate` as means of influencing autorotation behavior. We have only `portrait` set in `Device Orientation` section of `Deployment Info` for iPhone (as per guide here - https://developer.apple.com/library/content/technotes/tn2244/_index.html). Trying to check other orientations here didn't fix the issue.
5. We couldn't reproduce this issue with device laying down on the table surface. Only when you keep it in your hands.
6. Whenever this happens I can see in the logs that device orientation (`[[UIDevice currentDevice] orientation]`) is getting out of sync with status bar orientation (`[[UIApplication sharedApplication] statusBarOrientation]`). We log this information in `viewDidAppear` of the landscape view controller. 
   Status bar orientation reports the desired landscape (3) one but device orientation is portrait (1).
   In the normal flow they're both 3.
7. When this happens - we can fix it (at least on simulator) by rotating device.

**Question:**
Has anyone experienced similar problems? 
If yes - how did you resolve them? 
Is there anything specific we should be looking for in the console output or view hierarchy?

Any hints are highly appreciated.

**Update**

Here's some orientation related code we're using

**Info.plist**

```
...

</array>
<key>UIRequiresFullScreen</key>
<true/>
<key>UIStatusBarHidden</key>
<true/>
<key>UIStatusBarHidden~ipad</key>
<true/>
<key>UISupportedInterfaceOrientations</key>
<array>
    <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait</string>
</array>
<key>UISupportedInterfaceOrientations~ipad</key>
<array>
    <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight</string>
    <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft</string>
</array>
<key>UISupportedInterfaceOrientations~iphone</key>
<array>
    <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait</string>
</array>
<key>UIViewControllerBasedStatusBarAppearance</key>
<false/>

...
```

---

**AppDelegate**

```
...

- (UIInterfaceOrientationMask)application:(UIApplication *)application
  supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow:(UIWindow *)window
{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAllButUpsideDown;
}

...

// Showing portrait view controller
homeScreen.orientationMask = UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
homeScreen.preferredOrientation = UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait;
[self.window setRootViewController:homeScreen];
```

---

**Portrait View Controller**

```
- (UIInterfaceOrientationMask)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
    return self.orientationMask;
}

- (UIInterfaceOrientation)preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation
{
    return self.preferredOrientation;
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate
{
    return YES;
}

...

// Presenting landscape view controller
[self viewController] presentViewController:controller
                                   animated:YES
                                 completion:completion];
```

---

**Landscape View Controller**

```
- (UIInterfaceOrientationMask)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscape;
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate
{
    return YES;
}
```

Comment: Instead of asking what others do, the question is, how are _you_ implementing your view controllers and rotations? _Yours_ is the app that is having trouble. You need to show _your_ settings / code.

Comment: Thanks for your input @matt. I have already outlined our setup in **Additional Information** section 4. 
Do you have recommendations as per which exact information is missing there? 
My main concern with dumping too much code in the description is that I don't believe this issue is related to orientation code setup (it seemed to work fine (for several months) before we upgraded to iOS 10).

Comment: No problem. Let's see some code now, please.

Comment: @matt , I have added some orientation related code if you're still interested. Thanks.

Comment: What is the idea of the `homeScreen.orientationMask` stuff? If this is a view controller that wants to be in portrait, why does it not just return `.portrait` plain and simple?

Comment: Its orientation depends on device idiom (we use the same view controller for iPhone and iPad but different xibs). For iPad (where all view controllers are landscape) we set it up with landscape.

Comment: But how do you know that you are setting this value in time? It sounds to me, in fact, like that is not happening. Your approach here seems very risky. The view controller in question needs to be _born_ with the knowledge of what its supported orientation is, because it may be asked for that information at any time. I suspect that this is the cause of your difficulties.

Comment: You can see this happening in time (i.e. before setting it as a root view controller) in the **AppDelegate** code excerpt. Also - we have no problem with showing portrait oriented home screen view controller here. We have a problem with landscape one which we present from it.

Comment: Ah, okay. — Well, if it's any comfort, I've seen the same intermittent bug when doing a presented modal view controller that is supposed to force rotation. I would suggest filing a report with Apple.

Comment: Oh, that is a great feedback, thanks! I thought we were going crazy here for a moment. Filing an issue to Apple and we'll post an update here when we get a response.

Comment: The problem is that the bug is so hard to reproduce. If we knew how to reproduce it, we could work on a workaround...

Comment: I agree that this is a great challenge here but I'm also concerned that we don't have much control over orientation updates in general.
Going to wait for a response from Apple and then maybe try a couple of things like `attemptRotationToDeviceOrientation`.

Comment: We are thinking on the same lines. I tried that too.